# Find x in this equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can you please help me find x in this equation? My knowledge on the rules of algebra is honestly limited. I simply cannot isolate the x on one side.

$$\frac{(1+x)^3-1}{x}=3.1836$$

Comment: Can you expand $(1 + x)^3$?

Comment: $$\frac{(1+x\leftarrow\text{here it is})^3-1}{x\leftarrow\text{here it is again}}=3.1836$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Approach:

$$\frac{(1+x)^3-1}{x}=3.1836$$
$$\frac{(1+x)^3-(1)^3}{x}=3.1836$$

$$\frac{(1+x-1)((1+x)^2+1(1+x)+1)}{x}=3.1836$$
$$\frac{(x)((1+x^2+2x)+1+x+1}{x}=3.1836$$
$$x^2+3x+3=3.1836$$

$$x^2+3x-0.1836=0$$

Now, you can use the quadratic formula to calculate x.

Comment: What is so wrong in this? downvoter please comment.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted you. I don't think there is anything wrong with your solution. An upvote or downvote is simply someone's subjective opinion. In this case, I'm guessing that your solution is being compared to the other answers. Compare your answer to lab's. Which do you think is "better"?

Comment: i think we are here to show in how many different ways the problem can be approached. Mine may not be a simple solution as lab's but it is still a solution, and if we have started to downvote something which does not "look" good, I don't know where we are heading.

Comment: You're probably right. A better way might be to only allow upvotes. That way we can still put the "quality" of the answers into some ranking order. But, unfortunately that's not the case right now. Don't worry about it though. From what I've seen downvotes are rare, although in the past month they have been getting worse.

Comment: Thank you all for your  response!  You all gave good solutions,  simple or detailed, i appreciate them. I would vote up all your answers if i could, but being a newbie here doesn't allow that (sorry for my English).

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$$(1+x)^3=1+3x+3x^2+x^3\implies \frac{(1+x)^3-1}x=3+3x+x^2$$

Answer (score 2):

We have that: $$(a + b)^3 = a^3 + 3ab^2 + 3a^2b + b^3$$
Therefore: $$(x + 1)^3 = x^3 + 3x^2 + 3x + 1$$

Pluggin it in:
$$\begin{align}
&\frac{(x+1)^3 - 1}{x} = 3.1836\\
\implies &x^2 + 3x + 3 = 3.1836\\
\implies &x^2 + 3x + 3 - 3.1836 = 0\\
\implies &x^2 + 3x - 0.1836 = 0\\
\end{align}$$

This is a standard quadratic equation. Can you finish from here?